# Strange UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle + [cell imageView] behaviors

Tags: iphone, uitableview, uiimageview, tableview, sdwebimage

This question's been bugging me for a month and i've been resisting posting about it, but I can hold out no longer.  Here's what's going on:

I have an app with `UITableViewCell`s, all initialized as `UITableViewCellStyleDefault`.  For each one, I am setting the image view's image using the excellent SDWebImage package, which extends UIImageView to have a method for [UIImageView setImageWithURL:(NSURL*)url placeholderImage:(UIImage*)image].

The problem is that the images are showing up more narrow than they should be, on the tableView, but for some reason selecting a row makes it the correct size.  So does scrolling the row off screen, then onscreen, then offscreen.

What method should I be using to force cells to redraw?  I have found a few conflicting ideas and none of them have worked so far.  I feel like there's a simple call to UITableView to UITableViewCell I'm missing out on.  Also, where do I put this call? I have tried calls in `cellForRowAtIndexPath` and `willDisplayCell` .

Thanks for your help!

SDWebImage: https://github.com/rs/SDWebImage

Comment: Is your `UITableView` using the full width of the screen? And of which type is the table (plain/grouped)? Do you have any other content in the cell aside from having set text in `textLabel` and `detailTextLabel`? Have you tried debugging the sizes of your images before and after the content's been loaded?

Comment: If you want to redraw the cells to fix the image loading issue, you should probably make sure to do it as soon as your image's been loaded (I don't know if there's any `delegate` in `SDWebImage` that you can use?).

Comment: I have tried the `UITableView` as both grouped and plain.  There is an additional imageView on some of the cells - but the issue started before I added these.  The image sizes are fixed as square by the server they're loaded from.

Comment: What method would I use to force the cells to redraw?

Comment: You could use `-tableView:reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` (but that would reload the entire cell, which is the same as if you're scrolling in-and-out of the viewport) or just `-setNeedsDisplay:YES` on the cell's `contentView` or maybe the `cell.image`.

Comment: I'll try these.  Would it have different effects from `reloadData`?  Would it affect scroll position (as I'd be doing it fairly frequently)

Comment: `reloadData` reloads the entire `UITableView` (including recalculating all heights etc) whereas `-tableView:reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:` only reloads the specified rows. If the loading of a particular cell is an expensive process, it might affect your performance. Doing `-setNeedsDisplay:YES` is probably better, if you can get it to work. (And no, scroll position isn't affected.)

Comment: I am already calling `reloadData` and it isn't performing the desired effect, so I don't think `reloadRowsAtIndexPaths` will work either.  I'll try it and `setNeedsDisplay`, though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the issue - I had to just make my `SDWebImage` placeholder images the same aspect ratio as the images I'm trying to load.  As my server forces all my images to be 95x95, this was a relatively easy fix; I simply updated my `placeholder.png` to also be 95x95 (instead of some odd dimension it was, like 92x132)

Answer (score 0):

```
[[cell imageView] setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
```

this line makes the imageview show the image in its original resolution but fit to the image view size.

the main drawback is if u have the images in different sizes then each image will show i different sizes.... it should not looks good...

Comment: Since the bounty ends in 14 minutes and this does help me (though not with the original problem), here you go!