# Decreasing images in TableViewController when scrolling

Tags: ios, iphone, ios6

I'm trying to display a `UITableView` with a list of artists who read from Last.fm API. I store all the artists in an array, then I show a table with your name and your picture.

Initially the photos look good, but when I do scroll the images are very small.

This is the initial appearance:

[image]

This is the appearance after scrolling, with the problem:

[image]

This is my code for create the cells:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath   *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TopArtistCell";

    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    JSCArtist *artist = self.artists[indexPath.row];

    cell.textLabel.text = [artist name];
    [cell.imageView setImageWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:[[artist photo] thumbnail]]   placeholderImage: [UIImage imageNamed:@"default_photo.jpeg"]];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8024811/strange-uitableviewcellstylesubtitle-cell-imageview-behaviors

Answer (score 0):

The default imageView for a UITableView acts a little odd. I would just create a custom UITableViewCell subclass and do your own layout.